# Concrete not replacing Debut theme files?

Tags: git, themes, e-commerce, shopify

After creating a new store in shopify, I installed concrete using slate by cloning the repo https://github.com/Elkfox/Concrete.git and doing npm install. I then created the config.yml file in the root directory and entered the appropriate information then ran slate watch. Changes made in the files are being applied to the store. However, in the shopify editor thefiles for the Debut theme are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out `slate deploy`. That command is designed to initiate "a fresh build followed by a full deploy; replacing existing files on the remote server and replacing them with the full set of build files, and **removing remote files that are no longer in use**".

There are quite a few additional commands and options available in slate. Check out the docs at https://shopify.github.io/slate/commands/